# Parameter Map in jasper query

Tags: java, jasper-reports

This is my query in jasper.jrxml:

```
<queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT c.id,
    b.nom_beneficier,
    c.date_saisie,
    cat.designation,
    c.montant_brut,
    c.montant_rs,
    c.net_rs,
    id_exercice
    FROM 
    crs_certificat c,
    crs_beneficier b,
    crs_categorie_taux cat
    WHERE 
     c.id_beneficier = b.id 
     AND c.categorie = cat.id 
     AND id_exercice = //I want to pass a parameter here
     AND c.delete_stat = 0]]>
    </queryString>
```

How can I put paramter in this query and call it whenever I want ?

**EDIT:**
This is where I declared my parameter but jasper can't see it:

```
<subDataset name="tableDataset" uuid="7a7abe40-c5fa-40c9-bc37-a573ee7d748a">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="New Data Adapter "/>
        <parameter name="exercice" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[SELECT c.id, nom_beneficier, date_saisie, designation, montant_brut, montant_rs, net_rs
FROM crs_certificat c, crs_beneficier b, crs_categorie_taux cat
WHERE id_beneficier = b.id and categorie = cat.id AND id_exercice = $P{exercice}]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="id" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
        <field name="nom_beneficier" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="date_saisie" class="java.sql.Date"/>
        <field name="designation" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="montant_brut" class="java.lang.Double"/>
        <field name="montant_rs" class="java.lang.Double"/>
        <field name="net_rs" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    </subDataset>
```

Comment: Is this not where you would use the parameters.   $P{parameter name}

Comment: I edited my post.I don't know if I declared the parameter in he right place or not.

Comment: Are you trying to use the parameter in subdataset? if so, you can't call subdataset alone. You have to create some of reprot elements (Table, Crosstab or List), then set your subdataset for that report, and then map parameter value.